# How to create a go keyboard theme?

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard, themes, skins

I have developed many keyboard skins (better keyboard format) but I am having trouble making a go keyboard in eclipse. I am a designer not much of a programmer so I'm very clueless when it comes to this area.

The errors I am getting have to deal with the public.xml and all of the errors are linked to strings. I have decompiled a GO Keyboard theme and placed everything back into the Android Project into their correct places but I am still getting these errors (I know this probably not the best way to do this, however it's really the only way I know to get a quick template so I can change all the images to my liking and play around with some of the coding).

I can't find a downloadable template online or anything so I'm thinking I'm going to have to make this in eclipse. If someone can please point me in the right direction for this I would really appreciate it. Here's the public.xml I have

Comment: It would help if you posted an example of the errors you are getting.

Comment: Ok so for the public.xml I'm getting this for one string :Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: Public entry identifier 0x7f06000c entry index is larger than available symbols (index 12, total 
  symbols 12).

Comment: For the other errors (3) in the public.xml of the values folder it's just saying that the string is not defined.

Comment: Also for the strings in the values folder I have one item that has this error - - error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" 
  attribute?
 - error: Unexpected end tag string

Comment: Please update the question, not just add comments. Also, we can't actually see your XML file, so relating the errors to the file might be helpful.

Comment: @Will Hello, i m working on create multiple theme for keyboard.. can you help me? How to set new keyboard design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. The theme requires a specific package name which I wasn't using!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an answer to one error: the "Multiple substitution specified..." message is caused by a string with more than one `%` format specifier without using positional indexing. For example, you might have this (incorrect) message template:

```
<string name="error1">Error code %d when accessing file %s</string>
```

The correct way to write it would be to specify which argument index goes with each conversion specifier:

```
<string name="error1">Error code %$1$d when accessing file %$2$s</string>
```